# How to minimize auth requests for Sheets add-on

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm building an addon using the "new" Sheets AddOn API. The addon creates a menu with two subitems, "For Owner" and "For Viewers". Clicking on "For Owner" opens a sidebar with some functionality that checks if the user is the sheet owner. If so, the user can post some of the sheet data to an external service. Clicking on "For Viewers" opens a sidebar that fetches and displays data from the external service.

I understand that when the owner enables the add-on, a number of auth permissions are going to be requested based on the various features used by the code. However, when a viewer accesses the add-on, far less functionality is actually available to them in that code path. Yet, they get asked for all the same auth permissions.

So the question is --- how should I structure this so that the sheet viewers get prompted for the minimal auth permissions without limiting the richness of the feature for the owner function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to make two add-oms one for owners and one for viewers. Apps script does not currently support selective permissions.

Comment: Thanks Zig. I guess we could do this, though it would be a pretty clumsy experience. The owner would have to include two different add-ons for the sheet, and the viewers would need to know which one to use.